# non-casesensitive str.search(array[i]) in <script> tag is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have problem use array keyword and non-casesensitive search in innerHTML
I am trying write Greasemonkey JS which will remove  tags which are containning keywords

```
 function removebadcriptts() {

 var  scriptslinks = ['jumper.php','redirect.php'];
 var theLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

 for (var i=0; i<scriptslinks.length; i++)
 {
   for (var j=0;j<theLinks.length;j++)
   {
     if (theLinks[i].innerHTML.search("/"+scriptslinks[i]+"/i/")  !== -1)
      /keyword/i = regular expression for non-case is not working
     {     
      console.error("InnerHTML Keyword found ");      
      theLinks[j].parentNode.removeChild(theLinks[j]);
     } 
     else
     {
       console.error("InnerHTML Keyword  not found ");   
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Can anybody help howto remove and match this kind of scripts and remove from WEBpage also howto catch scripts which are injecting scripts into loaded webpage

Comment: Don't you mean remove scripts that have SRC containing a url? Not innerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Greasemonkey script is running, the scripts that are already on the page has already run. Removing them won't undo what these scripts did to the page.

Also the script that is inserted after the Greasemonkey script will not be catched, so this Greasemonkey probably will not work.

An alternative would be using NoScript add-on, because it is already designed to prevent scripts from running.

---

**Edit:** As the OP said that the primary problem is to make the search work, instead of storing patterns in a string inside an array, you can store patterns directly.

```
 var scriptslinks = [/jumper\.php/i, /redirect\.php/i];
```

And when matching

```
     if (theLinks[j].innerHTML.search(scriptslinks[i])  !== -1)
```

Note that a regex is passed directly to the search function. Also `theLinks[i]` should be `theLinks[j]`.

**Another solution:** Use a single pattern.

```
     if (theLinks[j].innerHTML.search(/jumper\.php|redirect\.php/i)  !== -1)
```

That way you don't have to make 2 level for loops, and I think it will be faster, as the engine can search for 2 patterns at once.

Comment: Doh. yeah, he needs www.proxomitron.info

Comment: I want remove tags when is page rendered post-processing no-script is active but I want remove some tags from rendered page such like unwanted icons or sections from some pages - primary problem is not if is possible do that with monkey problem is I am not able use "match" or "search" functions when is keyword in array (in-case mode) case mode is working. simply str.match(kw[0]) result is for ex. 14. but str.match(kw[0]/i) // str.match("/"+kw[0]+"/i")  is always return -1

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/shared/js/adsense.js?v=1"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
 google_ad_client = 'pub-4771975420977819';
 google_ad_channel = '1554776815';
 google_ad_output = 'js';
 google_max_num_ads = '4';
 google_ad_type = 'text';
 google_image_size = '300x250';
 google_feedback = 'on';
 //google_skip = '2';
 // -->
</script>

Comment: this script tag containning google keyword I want remove tag which contain keyword google also Google or gOoGle but I want use str.match or str.search solution str.indexOf is not capable search in-casesensitive

Comment: Just make both the pattern and subject lower case, then indexOf will work in a case-insensitive way (because they are all lower case!). So you can use `theLinks[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(scriptslinks[i])`

Comment: yes this will work but,.... I need reg-expr becouse need more complex matching and primary problem is still not solved howto use str.match or str.search when Keyword is in array how-to do this way

Comment: Updated my answer with the solution for your primary problem. Have a look. ;)

Comment: var scriptslinks = [/jumper\.php/i, /redirect\.php/i]; interesting string without quotes.  howto add thank and good answer here ?

Answer (score 2):

[`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) expects a [*RegExp* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). So try this:

```
theLinks[i].innerHTML.search(new RegExp(scriptslinks[i], "i"))
```

Although you can pass a string too, it would be used create an *RegExp* object like `new RegExp(string)` but you can’t set the *i* modifier with that.

Furthermore, you should escape the special character of a regular expression like the `.`. You can use this method to do so:

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/(?=[\\^$*+?.()|{}[\]])/g, "\\");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
 function removebadcriptts() {

 var  scriptslinks = ['jumper.php','redirect.php'];
 var theLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

 for (var i=0; i<scriptslinks.length; i++)
 {
   for (var j=0;j<theLinks.length;j++)
   {
     if (theLinks[i].src.toLowerCase().indexOf(scriptslinks[i]) !== -1)
     {     
      console.error("SRC Keyword found ");      
      theLinks[j].parentNode.removeChild(theLinks[j]);
     } 
     else
     {
       console.error("SRC Keyword  not found ");   
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: no this is matchind only exact strings request for help has other target (reg-expr functions for searching its more powerfull) thankyou for you answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using .Match, and i believe the regex would have to look like:

```
/scriptslink[i]/i
```

Comment: This is a regexp literal... the `scriptslink[i]` part will not be treated as an array.

Comment: Box9 is right this is a reason why was open question I tried use this notation and fail :p (this is /scriptslink[i]/i blind hint) Thai is right (above) his notation is exactly what I need